# Directive: append templateUrl as a sibling element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to append, as a sibling element, the contents of a template file using an attribute directive on an Input Text field.

I've tried this, but the contents of the template are being wrapped inside of `<input></input>` tags and this is not the desired behavior. I need to put the content of template file as a sibling of the input text. Anyway, angular code is executed without error on the template file.

I tried with Transclude but without success.

HTML

main page

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" name="inputName" ng-my-directive>
```

template.html

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <button ng-repeat="button in row">{{button}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
.directive('ngMyDirective', function ($compile) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude:true,
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       ...
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, transclude) {
       ...
         element.append(transclude());

    }
```

Currently, I have this (wrong) result:

```
<input type="text">
  <div>
   ...
  </div>
</input>
```

And I need this result:

```
<input type="text">
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
...
```

Thanks in advance for your effort!

Comment: Thanks Zanon! your answer fit perfectly to my needs! Sorry for delay, I'm in Italy and on Easter time I have to freeze any activities not related to family ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `element.after()` with the template contents:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .directive ('ngMyDirective', function() {
  
    return {
      
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        
        element.after('<h3>sibling content</h3>');
      }
    }    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" name="inputName" ng-my-directive>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is to append a "template.html" file. In this case, you could fetch the HTML contents in an ajax request. Example:

```
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function($http, $compile) {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element){

      $http.get('template.html')
        .then(function(response){
          element.after($compile(response.data)(scope));
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution I needed!